# What is the current limit for each individual fan port on a Fatal1ty B450 Gaming-ITX Asrock motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling

I'm building a 1U PC using the motherboard specified in the question. I want as much airflow as I can get in such a thin case. I have room for 3 40x40x28mm fans and the highest CFM fans I can find have a current draw of 0.9A max.

The board has two fan case connectors and both the [user manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Fatal1ty%20B450%20Gaming-ITXac.pdf) and the ASRock website state that

> The Chassis/Water Pump Fan supports the water cooler fan of maximum 2A (24W) fan power.

It's really not clear to me if both connectors combined are capable of 2A or if each is capable of 2A. If the former is true, I obviously need to use lower wattage fans.

Comment: You could power 12 V fans directly from the PSU - presumably you don't mind the noise.

Comment: I would need a different PSU. The one I am using plugs straight into the ATX port. Apart from that, it just has 4 wires for the CPU power connector. I could get a splitter and power them off that, or splice into the cable, but I'd like to avoid it. It's already pretty crammed as it is.

Comment: @user1969903 - It's the safer option, even if it supports 2 A, you are looking at 1.8 A and that is dangerously close to the amperage max of that header.  Plus that's only if you use 2 fans, there is no way to use a single header, and I suspect both headers can't be used (although I can't look at the specification myself to determine that).

Comment: @user1969903 Which PSU is it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton A Pico PSU but I don't know the model off the top of my head.

Comment: @Ramhound You can use both headers. It even allows you to set separate fan curves for each header. That's kind of why I'm hoping the rating is for each individual header. If I can't find the answer, I'll just use lower CFM fans. If I find that to bee inadequate, I will consider using the PSU to power them. With some custom wire splicing, I should be able to still use the PWM and RPM sense pins on the headers, right?

Comment: @user1969903 - I wouldn't for safety reasons.

Comment: @user1969903 The most powerful Pico-PSU I can find is the [160 W model](https://www.mini-box.com/picoPSU-160-XT). If there is only 160 W going to the motherboard, you probably don't need three screaming fans to keep it cool, especially if 32 W of that power is going to the fans.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The PC will ocasionally run in environments with ambient temperatures reaching 40*C, that's why I'd like to maximize airflow.

Comment: @user1969903 **If** the Pico PSU is one of the 12 V input models, you can use the 0 V and 12 V from the input to the PSU to power the fans and connect the PWM and sense lines from the fan to the M/B, somewhat as you described earlier but not taking the fan power from the Pico PSU's output. Make sure that the good-quality regulated 12 V DC power supply that is powering the PSU can take the total load at 40 °C. Oh, and connect the fans at the input connector rather than at the Pico PSU end to minimise voltage drop.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just looked it up, it's the M3-ATX which is capable of 125W (150W peak). Come to think of it, I think it is wiser to power the fans separately as you described, and not add further load to the PSU.

Comment: @user1969903 If you are powering the M3-ATX from a car then I have no idea if it would be safe to power the fans from the car, I expect it will damage the M/B because voltage transients might make their way through the sense line and maybe even the PWM line.

Comment: @user1969903 Maybe something like a [Mini ITX Enclosure for Car PC Applications](https://www.mini-box.com/CarPC-enclosure) would be better - it includes a 50 mm fan.